# how to get the identity with which a .vbs or a .asp file executes from within itself?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, identity, wsh, pid

I am looking for a way to get the identity of the process which executes a *.vbs file or a *.asp file. How to write code to determine the process identity from within the file itself? Suppose I execute the file, it should output the full name of the user (i.e. `domain\username`).

I've taken a look at [this](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/processes/#DetProcOwner.htm) code, but it lists all the processes and then displays the identity of each process. I don't think this is appropriate: if I use the same code in an asp file and executed it via a browser request, I am thinking it would be hard to determine which process is exactly executing it.

EDIT: hope this should explain my requirement better `->` what if I wanted my script file asp/vbscript to be run by a particular user and not anyone else?!

Comment: I'm not sure about ASP but in ASP.Net there is a config file that you can set permissions for each folder or file

Comment: That doesn't exist in ASP unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

Think this might solve at least part of your problem.  This is taken from an answer on [Google Answers](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=365115):

> You can grant them access to the site based on their Windows log-in
>   simply by unenabling Anonymous access and enabling Integrated Windows
>   authentication in the IIS console -> Anonymous access and
>   authentication control -> Edit... dialogue.
>
> Once authenticated with Integrated Windows, you can get their username
>   through Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").

Comment: Based on your question `what if I wanted my script file asp/vbscript to be run by a particular user and not anyone else?!` the above would allow you to do that.  If this isn't what you need then your question is still unclear and your need to clarify further what exactly it is you need to do